# How to resolve "sign in error" when using Youtube-dl for downloading my personal, private HOA video (hangout chats)

Tags: video, youtube

I am on 14.04 LTS. I just installed Youtube-dl from the software center. I use Hangouts on Air, which I set to private, and record video chats with acquaintances for demos, instructional videos etc. These video chats are great resources for me, but I can only access them by opening a browser on my desktop, and signing into Google.  I have some videos and source sheets in a folder on my desktop, but then I have  my HOA video chats only available on my Youtube, set to private. I'd like to download the private videos, so I can have everything in one folder on my desktop.
So I installed Youtube-dl today, thinking that would work. But when running it in the terminal, I get a failed error message saying "Youtube asks for sign in"

I suppose this makes sense, since the video is set to private. However, I can only access the URL when signed in and I am signed into my youtube account when I copy and paste the url in Terminal. So I was hoping it would work, given the fact that the URL would not be available *Unless* I was signed in. 
Do I have another option?

Answer (score 7):

youtube-dl -u "youtubeloginname" -p "youtubeloginpassword" url

Comment: You can omit the `-p "password"` part, and it will prompt you for your password. This is more secure because it won't write your password to any logs or expose it with ps.